# SyntaxError: Unexpected character '?' when trying to insert an image using PDFKIT

Tags: webpack, pdfkit

I'm currently using the PDFKIT library to create pdf's from my server and then email them to our staff.  The problem that I'm running into is that when I try to insert an image into the pdf document and then build my application, the application fails with this error:

```
D:\MyProj\node_modules\babel-register\node_modules\babel-core\lib\transformation\file\index.js:558
      throw err;
      ^

SyntaxError: D:/MyProj/public/Images/logo.jpg: Unexpected character '�' (1:0)
> 1 | ����
error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
```

I have read online that this could be an issue with webpack and it's image loader.  Currently I'm using the file loader library which is what others recommended with this issue but I'm still not having any luck.

Here is my letter.js file:

```
const PDFDocument = require('pdfkit');
import { salesTransport } from '../Utilities/EmailService';
import Logo from '../../../public/Images/logo.jpg';
const LINE_SPACING = 18;
const FONT_SIZE = 11;
const LETTER_HEADING = `HEADING HERE`

export const StoreLetter = (index,store,pdf) => {
    return new Promise(async(resolve,reject) => {
        try {
            !index ? null : pdf.addPage();
            pdf.fontSize(FONT_SIZE);
            pdf.font('Helvetica');
            pdf.img(Logo,320,280);
            pdf.text(LETTER_HEADING)
            pdf.text(`Some text here`)
            resolve(true);
        } catch (e) {
            console.error(`letter.StoreLetter: ${e}`);
            reject(e);
        }
    })    
}

export const CreateLetters = async () => {
    try {
        const pdf = new PDFDocument();

        for(let i = 0; i < 3; i++){
            await StoreLetter(i,false,pdf);
        }

        pdf.end();

        const attachment = [{filename: 'letters.pdf', content: pdf}]
        const msg = 
        `
        <div style="text-align:center;">
            <h1>Letters</h1>        
        </div>
        `
        SendEmail(msg,attachment,`Letters`)
    } catch (e) {
        console.error(`letter.CreateLetters: ${e}`)
    }
}
```

Here is my package.json file:

```
{
  "name": "my-app",
  "version": "0.0.2",
  "main": "index.js",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node src/entry",
    "start-dev": "npm-run-all --parallel build babel-node",
    "serve": "live-server public/",
    "build-linux": "clear && webpack && clear && yarn build-server && clear && yarn start",
    "build-windows": "cls && webpack && cls && yarn build-server && cls && set REACT_APP_ENV=development && yarn start",
    "build-server": "babel src/server -d src",
    "dev-server": "webpack-dev-server",
    "babel-node": "nodemon --exec babel-node src/server.js"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@googlemaps/google-maps-services-js": "^3.1.16",
    "aws-sdk": "^2.358.0",
    "axios": "^0.19.0",
    "babel-cli": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-core": "^6.26.3",
    "babel-loader": "7.1.1",
    "babel-plugin-transform-class-properties": "6.24.1",
    "babel-polyfill": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.7.0",
    "babel-preset-react": "6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-stage-0": "^6.24.1",
    "bcryptjs": "^2.4.3",
    "body-parser": "^1.18.2",
    "compression-webpack-plugin": "^6.0.2",
    "core-js": "^2.5.3",
    "css-loader": "0.28.4",
    "express": "latest",
    "file-loader": "^1.1.11",
    "fs": "0.0.1-security",
    "google-maps-react": "^1.1.4",
    "googleapis": "^67.1.1",
    "html2canvas": "^1.0.0-rc.3",
    "image-webpack-loader": "^4.6.0",
    "immutability-helper": "^2.4.0",
    "jquery": "^3.4.1",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^8.1.0",
    "jspdf": "^1.5.3",
    "lodash": "^4.17.14",
    "mailgun-js": "^0.22.0",
    "md5": "^2.3.0",
    "moment": "^2.29.1",
    "moment-timezone": "^0.5.32",
    "node-sass": "^4.11.0",
    "node-schedule": "^1.3.2",
    "nodemailer": "^4.7.0",
    "normalize.css": "7.0.0",
    "npm": "^6.10.1",
    "papaparse": "^5.3.0",
    "pdfkit": "^0.11.0",
    "promise-mysql": "^3.1.0",
    "prop-types": "^15.6.0",
    "react": "^16.0.0",
    "react-csv": "^1.0.14",
    "react-dom": "^16.0.0",
    "react-ga": "^3.1.2",
    "react-router-dom": "4.2.2",
    "react-scripts": "^2.1.3",
    "sass-loader": "6.0.6",
    "socket.io": "^2.0.3",
    "style-loader": "0.18.2",
    "table2csv": "^1.1.1",
    "twilio": "^3.24.0",
    "validator": "8.0.0",
    "webpack": "^4.44.2",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.3.12",
    "webpack-dev-middleware": "^3.5.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.1.14"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "concurrently": "^3.5.0",
    "npm-run-all": "^4.1.1"
  }
}
```

Here is my webpack.config file:

```
const path = require('path');
const CompressionPlugin = require('compression-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
  entry: ['babel-polyfill', './src/index.js'],
  mode: "development",
  output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, 'public'),
    filename: 'bundle.js'
  },
  plugins: [
    new CompressionPlugin(),
  ],
  module: {
    rules: [{
      loader: 'babel-loader',
      test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
      exclude: /node_modules/
    }, {
      test: /\.s?css$/,
      use: [
        'style-loader',
        'css-loader',
        'sass-loader'
      ]
    },{
        test: /\.(jpe?g|png|gif|svg|mp3)$/i,
        loaders: [
            'file-loader?hash=sha512&digest=hex&name=[hash].[ext]',
            'image-webpack-loader?bypassOnDebug&optimizationLevel=7&interlaced=false'
        ]
    }
    ]
  },
 
  devtool: 'cheap-module-eval-source-map',
  devServer: {
    contentBase: path.join(__dirname, 'public'),
    historyApiFallback: true
  }
};
```

I have checked and made sure that the path to the image is correct.  I have also tried using the `path` library and I get the same error message.  I have looked online for similar solutions and none of them worked for me.  If anyone has a solution to this or ideas I could try, that would help me a bunch. TIA!

Comment: Can you share the full stack trace of the error?

Comment: @tmhao2005 I have edited my post with the full stack trace.

Comment: I've tried to replicate by using the given info but no luck to replicate. Do you have a minimal reproducible repo?

Comment: @tmhao2005  I was actually able to figure out the solution to this.  I ended up using ```path.resolve(__dirname,'../../public/Images/logo.jpg)```